# SQL sub-query in entity framework 4.0

Tags: sql, entity-framework-4

how can i convert this SQL Query to Entityframework query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        EP.PrescriptionID
FROM    dbo.tEPPrescriptions EP 
WHERE   EP.CustomerID = 22
        OR ( EP.CustomerID IN (
             SELECT DISTINCT
                    AP.CustomerID
             FROM   dbo.tEPAdditionalPrescribers AP
                    INNER JOIN dbo.tAddresses A ON AP.SupervisorID = A.CustomerID
             WHERE  AP.SupervisorID = 22
                    AND AP.ActiveFlag = 1 )
             AND EP.LocationID IN (
             SELECT DISTINCT
                    AP.LocationID
             FROM   dbo.tEPAdditionalPrescribers AP
                    INNER JOIN dbo.tAddresses A ON AP.SupervisorID = A.CustomerID
             WHERE  AP.SupervisorID = 22
                    AND AP.ActiveFlag = 1 )
           )
```

Comment: Execute the SQL query directly, without modification.  http://www.nakov.com/blog/2011/01/12/native-sql-queries-in-entity-framework/

Comment: Well I can do that, But I am really interested to know if there is a way to make this fully EF query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like the following should do

```
from epp in context.EPPrescriptions
where 
    epp.CustomerID == 22 || (
    (from epap in context.EPAdditionalPrescribers where epap.SupervisorID == 22 select epap.CustomerID).Contains(epp.CustomerID) &&
    (from ....)
)
select epp.PrescriptionID
```

hope this help

By the way: what is an EPPrescription ?

Comment: Thanks it working. EPPrescription is a table name (hope that is what your questions was!)